# текст на видео в полноэкранном режиме просмотра видео

Tags: javascript, html, css, видео

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать плашку с текстом, которая будет отображаться при просмотре видео в полном экране? Получается сделать только когда видео не на весь экран.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оберните видео в какой-то `<div class="wrapper">` добавте данному диву `position:relative;` Для плашки дива, задайте стили по типу `position:absonute; top:0; left:0; z-index:2; width:50%; min-heght: 300px; height:100%;`
Должно сработать.
Дальше через медиа выражение рерулируйте размер шрифта в надпити.